# C# вывод слов с максимальным количеством букв

Tags: c#

Метод выводит слово с максимальным количеством букв, а что если слов с максимальным количеством букв несколько, как сделать?

```
static string Func(string data)
{
    int wordLen = 0;
    string desired_word = string.Empty;
    char[] chars = { ' ' };           
    string[]  words = data.Split(chars);
    foreach(string word in words)
    {
        if(word.Length > wordLen)
        {
            wordLen = word.Length;
            desired_word = word;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"слово макс. длинны: {desired_word} длинна: {wordLen}");
    return desired_word;
}    

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Func("Помогите решить задачу"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Не запоминать в цикле само слово. Искать только макс. длину. А затем, во втором цикле, выводить все слова такой длины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще один пример, но более громоздкий (громоздкость данного метода можно упразднить за счет сокращения кода в конце метода, в рамках ответа я старался максимально понятно донести мысль и описать код с помощью комментариев):

```
static List<string> Func(string data)
{
    // Справочник. Ключ - длинна слова. Значение - список слов этой длинны.
    var result = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    data
        .Split(' ') // Разделитель слов - пробел, получим массив слов
        .ToList() // Преобразуем массив в список, чтобы вызвать ForEach
        .ForEach(word => 
        {
            // Если такая длинна слова уже была добавлена в справочник
            if (result.ContainsKey(word.Length))
            {
                // Добавим слово по ключу - длинна слова, в список слов
                result[word.Length].Add(word); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Такая длинна не добавлена ранее - добавим новую пару с ключом длинны слова
                result.Add(word.Length, new List<string>() { word });
            }
        });

    // Из всех ключей (это колекция цифр) возьмем макс. значение - оно же макс. длинна
    var maxLengthKey = result.Keys.Max();
    // Возьмем список слов по указанной длинне (ключу)
    var maxLengthWords = result[maxLengthKey];

    // Отобразим сколько было найдено слов, и какая максимальная длинна в результате
    Console.WriteLine($"Was finded {maxLengthWords.Count} words with max length = {maxLengthKey}");

    // Вернем в качестве результата список слов с максимальной длинной
    return maxLengthWords;
}
```

Вызов функции немного поменяем, так как теперь она возвращает не строку, а список строк:

```
var words = Func("Помогите решить задачу с поиском слов макс длинннны");

Console.WriteLine("Next words has max length: ");
// Просто выведем список слов через обычный перебор коллекции
foreach (var word in words) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Нужно немного доработать функцию, так как разеделителем в данном примере является пробел (по Вашему примеру), ведь есть еще точки, запятые и прочие знаки препинания, которые можно считать разделителями, но для данного кода этого достаточно (для демонстрации работы).

Answer (score 6):

Немного в функциональном стиле. Вернет массив слов с максимальной длинной. Надо сказать, что ни ваш ни мой алгоритм ничего не знает про знаки препинания и считает границей слова - пробелы.

```
static string[] GetWordsWithMaxLenght(string data) =>
    data.Split(' ')
        .GroupBy(x => x.Length) //группируем по признаку длинны
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Key) //сортируем по убыванию длинны            
        .First() //берем первую группу 
        .ToArray(); //Преобразуем в массив
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще так можно:

```
data.Split(' ').Aggregate(result, (acc, word) =>
{
    if (result.Any() && result[0].Length < word.Length)
    {
        result.Clear();
    }
    result.Add(word);
    return result;
});
```